# Creating a vector of mutable Trait objects (sometimes shared) in Rust

Tags: rust

I need to create a stack of pointers with the following constraints:

- The pointers need to point to the same Trait object (so `Box` seems like a fit)
- Those Trait objects may need to be modified (`RefCell` may need to be used?)
- Two pointers in the stack may need to point to the same object (`Rc` seems like a fit)

Right now, the only way I've found to accommodate this is to use a `Vec<Rc<RefCell<Box<dyn MyTrait>>>>`. Is that the best solution though? It looks like a lot of pointer dereferences needed to access the objects.

Comment: `*p` conveniently goes through the whole pack of references and returns the trait object itself (as far as I recall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you exactly mean with:

> The pointers need to point to the same Trait object (so `Box` seems like a fit)

But if you are interested in storing objects of actually *different* types, then you need trait-objects and those need to be behind some sort of *pointer* such as a `Box`. And a `Box` is generally a good default (but there are alternatives).

> Those Trait objects may need to be modified (`RefCell` may need to be used?)

Well, actually, that could still be done with a `Box`.

> Two pointers in the stack may need to point to the same object (`Rc` seems like a fit)

Here, it gets difficult because in Rust *sharable* and *mutable* are kind of exclude each other. To be *sharable*, we need an `Rc`, which you can think of as a *shared box*. Then to make it mutable anyway, we can use *interior mutability* by using a `RefCell`. So, essentially a `Rc<RefCell<_>>`, which you can think of as a *sharable & mutable* `Box`.

Finally, if you put it all together into a `Vec` you get: `Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn MyTrait>>>` (no `Box`).

This allows you to have different types in the `Vec`, having some instances even multiple times in it, and still allowing mutable access to each of them.

Comment: For some reason when I tried `RefCell<dyn MyTrait>` it didn't work. But trying it now I manage to get the code to compile. Thanks!